# Will HANA lock the whole table when we add column to it?

Tags: locking, hana

I am using column store of HANA to implement dynamic table structure, like executing following SQL to add new column in Runtime:

```
ALTER TABLE test_table ADD (new_field1 VARCHAR(32));
```

I am wondering will hana lock the whole table when executes this SQL to measure the perfomance impact of this operation.

Apperaicate for any ideas.

Answer (score 0):

This depends on the HANA Version.
With HANA 2 SPS 04 and above an `ADD COLUMN` won’t lock the table (more precisely: it’s an *online* operation allowing write transactions on the table while the column is added).

But even without this, adding a column does not set a long lasting lock as this really is an update to the DB catalog and a tiny setup of empty in-memory storage structures for the new column.
The main scenario where this leads to lock-waits is when there are already open transactions on the table that in turn block the `ADD COLUMN` from proceeding.